# Jupyter kernel within a python virtual environment fails to start with Permission Denied error

Tags: permissions, virtualenv, jupyter-lab, virtualenvwrapper, pyenv

I am running **MacOS Big Sur** 11.2.3 + **pyenv** with **python 3.9.1** + **virtualenv** + **virtualenvwrapper**.

I activated my virtual environment using:

```
workon my-env
```

I downloaded ipkernel *within* my virtual environment:

```
python -m pip install ipykernel
```

I created a kernel:

```
ipython kernel install --user  —name=my-env
```

And then I tried to launch it:

```
jupyter labs
```

---

The first issue I ran into was that it complained about a module not being found and I noticed that it was looking for this module in my main brew python install (Cellar folder), not the virtual env I just created:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_8/bin/python3.9: No module named ipykernel_launcher
```

So I modified the **kernel.json** (manually for now) to point to the right path where I had installed ipkernel in my virtual environment.

```
{
 "argv": [
  "~/.virtualenvs/my-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "my-env",
 "language": "python"
}
```

But now I am getting a permission denied error!

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/me/.virtualenvs/my-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages'
```

Permissions on the path above seem fine - all folders are owned by me with group 'staff' and have read/write/execute permissions. I'm out of ideas on what to try next, any insight into what might be wrong would be highly appreciated!